# Regarding en and ja language prefix in url

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I am creating multilingual website, I have added Japanese language and prefix for that language is ja.I have set my default language as Japanese. Now I want to disable prefix ja. I don't want that ja to be visible in url.

Comment: Mhhh, if do you have only Japanese language on your site? As I know if Japanese is defaults language, then you shouldn't see the prefix. Site should be available on Japanese without prefix. For example as mysite.com/something

Comment: After setting Japanese as default language you also have to remove the prefix from here: /admin/config/regional/language/detection/url

Comment: I am working on Drupal 8. I have removed prefix still the prefix is displayed.

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Comment: @4k4 The suggestion in your comment did indeed work for me also. I could not find this option in Drupals admin interface, so I copy-pasted the path you provided. I do not know why I couldn't find this option.